# ios conditionally switch off facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

I integrated Facebook Ads SDK to my app. However, minimal supported iOS version for SDK is 5.0, and deployment target for my app is 4.3.

And, as expected, it crashes on app launch saying

```
dyld: Symbol not found: OBJC_CLASS$_NSJSONSerialization.
```

It happens at a very early stage of app start. Call stack looks as

Thread1:

```
dyld_fatal_error
_dyld_start
```

So I want to switch off Facebook SDK for iOS 4.3 and keep it for iOS >= 5.0. Is it possible? How can I do it in xCode? Or the only way is to split my app into two apps: for 4.3 and for >= 5.0?

**Update**

Accordingly to [NSJSONSerialization crash with Facebook iOS SDK 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480316/nsjsonserialization-crash-with-facebook-ios-sdk-3-5) marking `Foundation.framework` as `optional` helps. It really helps, but I cannot understand it. What has Foundation.framework to do with Facebook stuff??

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/a/3128299/440060 help?

Comment: @Mar0ux As I understand, the idea is to use "weak" or "optional" linking for frameworks. The problem is that I add FacebookSDK.framework manually to my project and it does not help to make it "optional". Can I add this framework "conditionally"?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You can't really add it "conditionally", since the check needs to happen at runtime. One option is to drop support for Facebook connect on iOS 5 (< 10% users), and weak link with `Social` framework. On a side note, have you considered dropping support for iOS 4? It would affect < 4% of your users.

Comment: @Mar0ux I have already marked Social, FacebookSDK, and a bunch of other frameworks "optional", but it did not help. What helped is marking Foundation.framework "optional" (see updated question). And I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **build phases** of your target. Under **Link binary with Libraries** select your framework and make it as ***optional***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but the framework is not a standard one. It is FacebookSDK.framework that I added manually into my project, and making it "optional" does not help. Please see my updated question.

Comment: It is, and I made it "optional" and it did not help. However, when I marked stadard "Foundation.framework" "optional", it stopped crashing. Sort of magic.

Comment: Actually facebook SDK uses NSJSonSerialization part of the foundation framework. That is not available in iOS4.3. Thats why it is crashing